# how to print id from ajax result

Tags: json, ajax

how to print id from ajax data

**data.id** is undefined

```
$.ajax({
    url: "userdetails",
    type: "get",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $("#ajaxdata").append(data);
        alert(data.id)
    }
});
```

data value is below

```
[{
    "id": 28,
    "firstname": "asddsf",
    "lastname": "sss",
    "email": "terrymol.christian@roarsinc.com",
    "role_id": 1,
    "status": "Active"
}, {
    "id": 87,
    "firstname": "df",
    "lastname": "dsfsd",
    "email": "sdfsdf@dfds.hgj",
    "role_id": 1,
    "status": "Active"
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The response would be not treated as JSON *if the data type is not being specified or server is not mentioning it in the response header*.

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "userdetails",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $("#ajaxdata").append(data);
        alert(data.id)
    }
});
```

**Update:**

The response looks like an array of objects. You would need to try `alert(data[0].id)`